# Unable to access Linux share from a Windows machine with NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME error

Tags: debian, filesystems, mount, windows, samba

On the Linux machine I changed the smb.conf like this:

```
[john]
path = /root/john/downloads
available = yes
valid users = john
read only = no
browsable = yes
public = yes
writable = yes
```

The path /root/john/downloads is mounted like this:

```
mount -o umask=0000,gid=1001,uid=1001 /dev/sdb1 /root/john/downloads
```

where gid and uid are `john`.

Now when I try to access the share with the Windows machine \\192.168.0.2\john I get the error `network path was not found` with Wireshark I saw it's the NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME error. What is wrong with this, why isn't it working?

When I choose /home/john as the path it works perfectly.

Comment: What's the output of `testparm -s`

Comment: And your distribution name

Comment: It's Debian Squeeze. The output of testparm is [here](http://pastebin.com/01Rbyjw5).